# Progress dialog in Multipart Upload Request

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Multipart method to upload a pdf file from Android to server.

```
fun uploadMultipart() {

        val apiUrl = getString(R.string.service_api)+"addDoc"
            try {
                val uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                MultipartUploadRequest(this@AddDocSecondActivity, uploadId, apiUrl)
                        .addFileToUpload(PdfPathHolder, "resource_center_pdf")
                        .addParameter("title", titles.text.toString().trim())
                        .addParameter("tags",  tag.text.toString().trim())
                        .addParameter("categoryid", categoty_id)
                        .addParameter("country_id", country_id)
                        .addParameter("description", txtDiscription.text.toString().trim())
                        .addParameter("member_id", preferenceHelper?.getMyData(Utilities.USERID)!!)
                        .setNotificationConfig(UploadNotificationConfig())
                        .setMaxRetries(2)
                        .startUpload()

            } catch (exc :Exception) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Error While uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
}
```

**How can i show Progress dialog, so that user knows how much file has been uploaded?**

Comment: how to implement progress dialog in multipart  upload request in kotlin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490886/implementing-progressdialog-in-multipart-upload-request