# Intent move from one to other activity and do oncreate in other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-volley, android-lifecycle

I have 2 activity, Tambah and Tampil activity.

I use Tambah activity to add new data (form and button submit), and after submit, it will move to Tampil activity. in Tampil activity will show the list view of data (i'm using Volley). all script works, no error. but in Tampil activity only showing old data (like before add), not showing the newest data.

here my Tambah acitivity

```
package com.example.arif.upload;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Tambah extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

//Declaring views
private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private ImageView imageView;
private EditText editText;

//Image request code
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

//storage permission code
private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

//Bitmap to get image from gallery
private Bitmap bitmap;

//Uri to store the image uri
private Uri filePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tambah);

    //Requesting storage permission
    requestStoragePermission();

    //Initializing views
    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

    //Setting clicklistener
    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/*
 * This is the method responsible for image upload
 * We need the full image path and the name for the image in this method
 * */
public void uploadMultipart() {
    //getting name for the image
    String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();

    //getting the actual path of the image
    String path = getPath(filePath);

    //Uploading code
    try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        //Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Konfigurasi.url_tambah_tentor)
                .addFileToUpload(path, "foto") //Adding file
                .addParameter("nama", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        Intent move = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tampil.class);
        startActivity(move);

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


//method to show file chooser
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

//handling the image chooser activity result
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//method to get the file path from uri
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}


//Requesting permission
private void requestStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }
    //And finally ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}


//This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {

        //If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if (v == buttonUpload) {
        uploadMultipart();
    }
}
}
```

and here Tampil activity

```
package com.example.arif.upload;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tampil extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView list_tentor;
ArrayList<String>nama;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tampil);

    list_tentor = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_tentor);
    nama = new ArrayList<String>();

    list_tentor.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent pindah = new Intent(Tampil.this,Tambah.class);
            pindah.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(pindah);
            finish();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue req = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Konfigurasi.url_tampil_tentor, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray tentor = jo.getJSONArray("tentor");
                for (int i = 0; i < tentor.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject pertentor = tentor.getJSONObject(i);
                    nama.add(pertentor.getString("nama"));
                }
                Tampiladapter ta = new Tampiladapter(getApplicationContext(),nama);
                list_tentor.setAdapter(ta);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    req.add(sr);
}
}
```

how can when Intent from Tambah activity to Tampil activity, the Tampil activity reload all data include newest data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not waiting until data is uploaded and redirecting to next screen.
Try this answer 
[Implementing ProgressDialog in Multipart Upload Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490886/implementing-progressdialog-in-multipart-upload-request)

> `onCompleted` redirect to next screen